# How to filter product by Category wise in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-filter

I am trying to filter according to the category but it's displaying all products on each category page, but I want filter according to the category page, please check my code and let me know how I can do it.

here is my `models.py` file...

```
 class SubCategory(models.Model):
        subcat_name=models.CharField(max_length=225)
        subcat_slug=models.SlugField(max_length=225, unique=True)
        category = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='subcategoryies', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

and here is my product models.py file...

    class Product(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=225)
        slug=models.SlugField(max_length=225, unique=True)
        subcategory=models.ForeignKey('SubCategory', related_name='prosubcat', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name


class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['saleprice', 'title','veg_non','brand','supplement']

def SubCategorySlugListAPIView(request, subcat_slug):
    category = Category.objects.all()
    subcategories = SubCategory.objects.all()
    product = Product.objects.all()
    brands=Brand.objects.all()
    f = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
    supplement=Supplement.objects.all()
    featured=Product.objects.filter(featured=True).order_by('-created_at')[0:6]
    high = Product.objects.all().order_by('-saleprice')
    if subcat_slug:
        subcategory = get_object_or_404(SubCategory, subcat_slug=subcat_slug)
        productlist = product.filter(subcategory=subcategory)
        paginator = Paginator(productlist, 12)
        page_number = request.GET.get('page')
        product = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    template_name = 'mainpage/cat-products.html'
    context = {'product': product,
           'subcategories': subcategories, 'subcategory': subcategory, 'category': category, 'featured':featured, 'high':high, 'brands':brands, 'supplement':supplement, 'filter':f}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

i know there are need to merge these code  `f = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())` and this `productlist = product.filter(subcategory=subcategory)`, using `productlist` i am getting product according to the category but when I do filter with `filter` then all products displaying on each category page. please merge both code and give me a correct solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
def SubCategorySlugListAPIView(request, subcat_slug):
    
    # First get the category object.
    subcategory = get_object_or_404(SubCategory, subcat_slug=subcat_slug)
    
    # then filter the products on this category

    productlist =Product.objects.filter(subcategory=subcategory)
```

**EDIT:** There is no necessary to write extra `filter` method here.
The basic thing you need is you need to get the single category object first and filter the products on this category from Product model.

```
def SubCategorySlugListAPIView(request, subcat_slug):
    subcategory = get_object_or_404(SubCategory, subcat_slug=subcat_slug)
    productlist = Product.objects.filter(subcategory=subcategory)
    paginator = Paginator(productlist, 12)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    product = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    brands=Brand.objects.all()
    supplement=Supplement.objects.all()
    featured=Product.objects.filter(featured=True).order_by('-created_at')[0:6]
    high = Product.objects.all().order_by('-saleprice')            
       
    template_name = 'mainpage/cat-products.html'
    context = {'product': product,
           'subcategories': subcategories, 'subcategory': subcategory, 'category': category, 'featured':featured, 'high':high, 'brands':brands, 'supplement':supplement}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Also you can filter the related products like this(other way)

```
subcategory = get_object_or_404(SubCategory, subcat_slug=subcat_slug)
productlist = subcategory.prosubcat.all()
```

Comment: using `filter` i am getting all products on each category page (`https://prnt.sc/tn0sah`), and using `product` i am getting products according to a particular category, but I want the product in each category after applying the filter. so how I can get `subcategory` products using this `f = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all()`, any other solution is appreciated

Comment: @sainitor you don't need to write extra `filter` method. You can simply get the category object and filter products from Product model

Comment: do you have any reference for this, where I can filter products using the `Product` model...

Comment: you can see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

for example:

In `models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Category(model.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=50)

class Item(model.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category,related_name='ITEM')
```

In `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Category

def category_filter(request, slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
    data = category.ITEM.all()
    render(request, TEMPLATE_NAME, context={'data':data})
```

In urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import category_filter

urlpatterns = [
    path('category/<slug:slug>/', category_filter, name='Category'),
]
```

now if url is some thing like

> localhost/category/froots/

all items with ***froot*** category will be displayed.

Comment: Note:
if you use generic views you should load slug from `self.kwargs.get('slug')`