# How to display Foreignkey Data in Django html page?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to get data from related foreign-key models, but I am unable to get data from the related model, Please let me know how I can do it. I want to display `name` value from `Model2` table..

here is my `models.py` file...

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    cus_name=models.Charfield(blank=True)

class Model1(models.Model):
    namefield=models.Charfield(blank=True)

class Model2(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(default=None)
    model1=models.Foreignkey(Model1, related_name='model_one', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   customer=models.Foreignkey(Customer, related_name='customer_data', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

here is my `views.py` file...

```
def display_data(request, id):
     test_display=Model1.objects.filter(pk=id).first()
     return render(request, 'page.html', {'test_display':test_display})
```

here is my `test.html` file where i am displaying `name` from `Model2` table

```
<p>{{test_display.model_one.name}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of `filter(...).first()`, use `get()` or [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) method:

```
 from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

 def display_data(request, id):
     test_display=get_object_or_404(Model1.objects.prefetch_related('model_one'), pk)  
     # or Model1.objects.prefetch_related('model_one').get(pk=pk)
     return render(request, 'page.html', {'test_display':test_display})
```

And in the template, use [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/) to query Model1 instances:

```
{% for object in test_display.model_one.all %}
    {{ object.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

As the relation between Model1 and Model2 is many to one due to ForeignKey, you will get multiple Model1 objects from reverse querying Model2 instance. If you want only one object to stored for Model2, then consider using [`OneToOne`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) relation.

Comment: it's working perfectly, but I want `Customer` data also from `Model2`, I want to display `name` from the `Customer` model...Please check my updated Question

Comment: then use `{{ object.customer.name }}`

Comment: It's working Perfect,  but above `for loop` giving me output in a single line...eg-`name1 name2` but I want with `comma-separated` like this `name1, name2`

Comment: Hello Rudra, could you please solve this issue...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63840351/how-to-give-permission-in-django

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to fix your syntax error:

```
def display_data(request, id):
    test_display = Model2.objects.filter(pk=id).first()
    context = {
        'test_display': test_display
    }
    return render(request, 'page.html', context)

# render instead of ender
```

second of all try to access the Queryset like so:

```
<p>{{  test_display.name  }}</p>
```

Comment: it's giving me the error `Model1 Object is not iterable`

Comment: it will display the name from `Model1` but i want to display the name value from `Model2`

Comment: @sainitor then just query model2, see answer

Comment: I want to get data of `Model2` using `Model1` in the query, because I have multiple data stores in `Model1` and `Model1` related to other Models also...So my priority is to display data using `Model1`