# How to display Data in Ascending and Descending Order in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-filter

I am creating my custom admin panel in Django, i don't want to use django default admin panel, But i want sorting filters in dajngo, If a user click on `email` then email should be in `ascending` order, and if the user click again on email then the `emails` will be in descending order, Please let me know how i can do it.

Here is my `models.py` file...

```
    class Model1(models.Model):
        email= models.Charfield(blank=True)
        phone= models.Charfield(blank=True)
```

here is my `views.py` file...

```
    def display_data(request):
        test_display=UserFilter(request.GET, 
        queryset=Model1.objects.select_related('customer__user))
        
         paginator = Paginator(test_display.qs, 10)
         page_number = request.GET.get('page')
         testdisplay = paginator.get_page(page_number)
     return render(request, 'page.html', {'test_display':test_display, 'testdisplay':testdisplay})
```

here is my `page.html` file

```
    <th><a href="javascript:void()">Email (CLick on this field)</a></th>
      {% for i in testdisplay %}
      <tr>
       <td>
         {{i.email}}
       </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```

here is my `filters.py` file code...

```
calss UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
    models= Model1
    fields ['type','status']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
# template
<th><a href="?order_by=email">Email (CLick on this field)</a></th>

# view
def display_data(request, id):
   test_display=Model1.objects.all()
   order_by = request.GET.get('order_by', None)
   if order_by:
       test_display = test_display.order_by(order_by)
   return render(request, 'page.html', {'test_display':test_display})
```

Here I am sending a URL querystring parameter `order_by`. In the view, it will get the querystring parameter from `request.GET`, and then order that queryset accordingly.

### Update

Based on [documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#orderingfilter) you can add `OrderingFilter`:

```
from django_filters import FilterSet, OrderingFilter

class UserFilter(FilterSet):
   order_by = OrderingFilter(fields=(('email','email')))
   # rest of the code
```

And update the link in HTML:

```
<a onClick="window.location.href=window.location.pathname+'?order_by=email&'+window.location.search.substring(1)">
```

I am using inline JavaScript to resolve this issue, you can write a proper function for this.

Comment: it's giving me this error...`UserFilter` object has no attribute `order_by`...I am using pagination also...If required please let me know I will submit my `UserFilter` code also

Comment: Please check my updated question, i have updated the `filters.py` file and pagination also...I have multiple fields in my `filters.py` file...

Comment: Could you please update your answer using pagination also...

Comment: The code itself should not cause any issue witn pagination. Do you have any issue with your current pagination? If there is an erro, please share the error with stacktrace. Thanks

Comment: this is working perfect, but when I click to `next page` it's replaced with pagination URL..for eg- my current url after ordering is `127.0.0.1/customer/?order_by=email`, but when i click on `page 2` using pagination, then it's replacing with `127.0.0.1/customer/?page=2`, but it should be `127.0.0.1/customer/?order_by=email&page=2`

Comment: Please solve this pagination issue, I will accept your answer...

Comment: Basically you need javascript to resolve this issue. I have added an inline solution in the answer

Comment: Could you please solve this issue also, i want to display `Model2` data using `Model1`...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63781362/how-to-display-foreignkey-data-in-django-html-page