# How to Give Permission in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication, django-permissions, django-auth-models

I am working on Django and I create my Custom Admin Panel, But I want the same functionality of permission like as Django Default admin Panel. I create functionality for the `Blog` model in my Dashboard, if I log in as a super-admin and I give Normal User to `blog view only` permission then Normal user should not access `add` and `edit` access on my dashboard, Currently normal user also can access `add` and `edit` access on the admin panel which I developed.
I added the functionality for `Admin` and `Normal User`, if a user is `admin` then he can access my `dashboard` otherwise he/she will re redirect on the homepage.

But my problem is, how I can create permission-based functionality on my `dashboard`, I will give permission from `Django` default admin panel.

Please let me guide, Does I need to create the same URL's like Django default admin panel or there is another way to solve this issue. it's a very big problem for me please give me the correct solution.
please send if you have any documentation or solution for this.

Comment: Django gives batteries included model permission system. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382232/django-query-distinct-values-works-but-i-cant-use-the-query-result